# Being charged with DDoS – my IP address shows on hacked computer

Tags: network, ip, ddos

On July 21 2020 a business was subjected to DDoS attacks crashing their system  and causing a very expensive problem.

My IP address was used and I am being blamed and have to explain how my IP address was identified as the source of the problem.

For what it's worth I have since discovered a lot of malware running on my machine.

1. Is it possible that a hacker used "dirty tricks" to remotely drive my computer and initiate DDOS attacks? Backdoor software?
2. Is there a way to spoof someone's IP address making it look like it was the victim's actions?

Comment: What if you launched the DoS attack, and then infected your own machine hoping it would sound like a plausible excuse? I guess some serious investigation is needed, including seizing your devices. This is probably a legal question that is off-topic here.

Comment: To answer your on-topic question, yes, if your machine is part of a botnet, then the hacker will use it to launch attacks (not only for DDoS but maybe also for spam, fraud, network scans, as a proxy in general, etc.)

Comment: Your 3rd question is completely off-topic and unanswerable. It's all up to who you have to convince.

Comment: Anyone asking you "to explain how my IP address was identified" should already know the details in my answer below. If they do not, then they lack the knowledge to accept any answer. It sounds like you have a bigger problem than just your IP in a log.

Comment: Who asked you to explain yourself? The ISP? Don't answer. The lawyer of the company? Don't answer. Are you being charged? Get a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that a hacker used "dirty tricks" to remotely drive my
> computer and initiate DDOS attacks? Backdoor software?

Absolutely. Remote access, backdoors, bots, etc. they all give someone else access to your machine. [Botnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet) are used for a variety of actions, including DDoS attacks.

> Is there a way to spoof someone's IP address making it look like it
> was the victim's actions?

Absolutely. But it depends on the type of DDoS. I can, from my home, craft traffic to a target using any IP address I like. Any response won't come back to me, though.

Comment: Nowadays ISPs employ a technique to verify whether a source IP address is actually you in order to detect source IP spoofing in UDP.

Comment: @defalt that ability has been in place since 2000, when I was at a company developing DDoS protection appliances. Whether or not the ISP turns it on or not is the trick.

Comment: What is it called?

Comment: @defalt It's called source-filtering.  Most carrier-grade switches can do it, but many ISP's are reluctant to enable this, because it adds latency.

Comment: Also take into account that IP spoofing is ilegal in some countries and the ISPs needs to implement measures to avoid that.

Comment: @camp0 where is it illegal? That sounds strange.